# Function Error in R, non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, function, arguments, normalization, min

I'm creating this function in R, that will create normalization. In `data2`, `YearlyIncome` column has large difference from lowest value to highest value. I want normalization convert value from 0 to 1.

The value values of apply function overwrite to `YearlyIncome`.

```
    > x <- data2$YearlyIncome
> a <- min(x)
> b <- max(x)
> fun <- function(x){  (x - a) /  (b - a) }
> fun(data$YearlyIncome)
Error in data$YearlyIncome : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
> fun <- function(x){ (x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x)) }
> fun(data2[1])
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables 
But I got this error:
>Error in x - a : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

So what do I do now?

Comment: I just answered this question via email, did it not fix your problem?  Show us the full `data2` data frame.

Comment: I would use `fun(data2[,1])` as `data2[1]` is still a data.frame.  Also, please check the `str(data2)` to see if the first column is a numeric variable.  I tested with an example data and it is working for me.

Comment: @akun so akun can you change your answer to it will replace my old lines of error? like I'm just lost what should be after I define my function fun <- function(x){ (x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x)) }?

Comment: @akun also akun is there way to view the csv file in R studio?

Comment: @Lee `data$YearlyIncome` is a vector, also `data[,1]` is a vector, here we are subsetting the 1st column.  You were already using the `View`, right

Comment: the first error comes from a typo (`data` instead of `data2`), the second error probably comes from the fact that the frist column of `data2` is not numeric, but we don't have enough information to solve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, we are subsetting the first column.  The `apply` is not needed for that.

```
fun(data$YearlyIncome)
```

where

```
fun <- function(x){ (x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x)) }
```

Comment: sorry I still get the following error: > help("read.csv")
> ?read.csv
> data2 <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = TRUE)
> options(max.print = 1000000)
> x <- data2$YearlyIncome
> a <- min(x)
> b <- max(x)
> fun <- function(x){  (x - a) /  (b - a) }
> View(fun)
> YearlyIncome <- apply(data2[1],2,fun)
Error in x - a : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: @Lee As I mentioned earlier, if you are using a single column `data2[1]`, apply won't work and is not needed.

Comment: @akun so for the last step what do I do, just YearlyIncome <- (data2[1],2,fun). Sorry but can you please write an answer in the last 4 steps? I promise I will accept it. Just a beginner here.

Comment: @Lee why can't you do `fun(data2[1])`  BTW, I don't know why you are defining 'a' and 'b' outside the function and in that way what is the use of the `fun`?  Please check the `fun` in my answer.

Comment: @akun sorry I think what I means CSV is a basically a file with 14 columns and A LOT OF Rows of data. I think I got confused in understanding your answer. so apply cannot use in a single column case?

Comment: @also where should I put fun(data$YearlyIncome)? right after > View(fun)?

Comment: @Lee `apply` is a another way of writing a `for` loop.  If you have 1 column, why would you loop for that single column

Comment: @Lee `fun(data$YearlyIncome)` is only needed with the `min` and `max` defined inside the function.

Comment: @akun sorry to bother you, but can I email you? Mine is gethbonow on gmail. Can you please consider email since  I can't type too long on here. I apologize but I'm just a beginner student and has to work later. You can email me if you don't give out your personal info. Please consider help!

Comment: @akun please consider help me!

Comment: @Lee I would have certainly liked to help you.  It is better you post the questions in stackoverflow in a reproducible way so that it will be viewed by many people and you get the help from a lot of people rather than from a single person by email.

Comment: @akun sorry what I meant was I can't post another question soon. Please understand, I'm just really lost right now I keep getting erros. Can I post them on the current question?

Comment: @akun oh sorry what I meant was I will post my latest error on here if I get any